# how can i set darkness in a plot curve in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
plot(x, y, c='red')
```

I can get a red curve, but if i want to set darkness of every point in this curve, is there any methods?

Comment: You need alpha parameter. Search for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use both `plot` and `scatter`: `scatter` accepts a list of colors so that you can have a gradient of reds for example using `colorsys` lib:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import colorsys


reds = [colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(0, 1, i/10) for i in range(10)]
x = range(10)
y = x

plt.plot(x, y, "r", zorder=1)
plt.scatter(x, y,
            c=reds,
            s=100,
            zorder=2)
plt.show()
```

[image]